# How do I download and replace an AppGroup container using XCode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-group

I'm aware of how to download and replace the filesystem container for a particular iOS application using XCode 6's Devices window.

However for an application I'm developing I need to be able to download and replace a shared AppGroup container for debug purposes. This would enable me to simulate situations in the AppGroup's folder content for testing purposes.

Can anyone advise me of how I can do this? Is it possible?

Update:
I should clarify this is for testing on a real iOS device. I have already been successful in modifying AppGroup folders when using the iOS Simulators - as these can be accessed directly via Finder/the Mac's file system.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. I will solve this with a (test) button in my app where I copy the (interesting) contents for the shared group back to the application folder. So far I have not seen any other solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have also considered a similar solution myself - the idea being to develop a dedicated test harness application that will ensure the target application is running and then carry out tests by submitting files to the SharedApp group - waiting on any expected feedback to be made available within a reasonable amount of time.